# Requirement Specification for SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Goal:
The goal is to create a real-based project in SP in order to improve my ability by creating home made SP project.

Problem:
I would like read a requirement specification for a SPproject because I wanna read it and create it in reality.

The main problem I'm facing is that i cannot find a real-based  and previous requirement specification for SP. Where can I find it?

Information:
- I'm using SharePoint 2013, Visual Studio 2012 and SQL server 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You find a lot of different [Case Studies on Sharepoint 2013](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=sharepoint%202013%20case%20study) using Goolge. All could easely be transferred to a requirement specification, where you have to do some architechtural work before you can start coding. Here are the first three in the list:

- [**Cambridgeshire Constabulary** Constabulary Lowers Costs, Increases Public Safety with Enhanced Collaboration](http://www.microsoft.com/casestudies/Case_Study_Detail.aspx?CaseStudyID=710000001618)
- [**ASB Bank** Bank Innovates Work Environment, Boosts Performance with Social Collaboration](http://www.microsoft.com/casestudies/Case_Study_Detail.aspx?CaseStudyID=710000001616)
- [**Kentucky Community and Technical College System** College System Brings Its Organizations Together with Line-of-Business Integration](http://www.microsoft.com/casestudies/Case_Study_Detail.aspx?casestudyid=710000002231)